# Speed up subdocument access in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where I wan’t to access only specific subdocuments with an aggregation query.

Consider documents where each document describes a country having a subdocument for each city. Now I want to access only the subdocument for Munich.

```
{
_id: "123abc",
name: "Germany",
"someAttribute": ...
cities: [
    {
        "name": "Berlin", 
        "someAttribute": ...
    },
    {
        "name": "Munich", 
        "someAttribute": ...
    },
    {
        "name": "Bonn"
    },
    ...
]
}
```

I know I can add an index to speed up the retrieval of the document containing the relevant subdocument for Munich. What I’m looking for though is a way to speed up the retrieval of the subdocuments itself. Because for large document it still takes a long time for mongodb to scan the document and extract the relevant subdocument.

Answer (score 0):

Given we have this document within mongodb

```
{
    _id: "123abc",
    name: "Germany",
    "someAttribute": ["a","b","c"],
    cities: [
        {
            "name": "Berlin", 
            "someAttribute": ["a","b","c"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Munich", 
            "someAttribute": ["a","b","c"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Bonn"
        }
    ]
}
```

We can then do the following aggregation query

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: { "cities.name" : "Berlin" } },
    { $unwind: "$cities" },
    { $match: { "cities.name" : "Berlin" } },
    { $project: { "city" : "$cities" } }
]);
```

This will limit the size of the return document to just the city, thus saving bandwidth and transfer time.

You should however ensure that cities.name has a index

```
db.test.createIndex( { "cities.name" : 1 } );
```

Comment: Yes - your solution is exactly what I have right know. The Problem is that mongo still has to scan through all the cities in the document and find the right one - I was looking for a way to make mongo only read the relevant part of the document containing the city I'm looking for.

Comment: your correct, mongodb will load the whole document (but only the one that matched) in to memory to do the operations on it. pretty sure there isn't a way round this, you could just model you document differently?